# Order of convergence of derivative limit

Tags: limits, derivatives

What is the order of convergence of this expression?:

$\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}-f'(t)$

(How fast does the limit of the definition of derivative approches the derivative compared to $h$ asymptotically?)

Can we say something in general? What if $f\in C^p$ or $f\in C^\infty$?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

It looks like for the polinomials, exponential and trigonometric functions the order is $h$ (just by looking at the proof of the derivative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If f is smooth enough, it will be of order $n-1$ such that $f^{(k)}(t)=0$ for all $1<k<n$ and $f^{(n)}(t)\neq 0$.

You can see it by approximating the function using it's taylor polynomial of order $n$.
$$f(t+h)-f(t)=f'(t)h+f^{(n)}(t)h^n+o(h^n)$$
$$\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}-f'(t)=f^{(n)}(t)h^{n-1}n+\frac{o(h^n)}{h}=f^{(n)}(t)h^{n-1}+o(h^{n-1})$$

Comment: Using the Taylor polynomial, of course! Thank you.